# How could I transfer message dynamically in Sftp Inbound adapter through Spring DSL in java 1.7

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Sftp inbound flow and I got the session information from DefaultSftpSessionFactory. But I need to implement mulitple session information dynamically which I will get from database table. That means I have multiple number of Sftp server details that I need to implement in my integration flow. Now I have done with file transfer from single source to single destination but I need to implement multiple source to multiple destination. So can any one provide some pointer on this.

This is my session Factory...Here I have a single Sftp server information but how to configure multiple server details.

```
    @Autowired
    private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;

    @Bean
    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(
                true);
        factory.setHost("111.11.12.143");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("sftp");
        factory.setPassword("*******");         
        return factory;
    }
```

and this is my Sftp Inbound flow..

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
    System.out.println("enter sftpInboundFlow....."
            + sftpSessionFactory.getSession());     
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                    .preserveTimestamp(true).remoteDirectory(remDir)
                    .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                    .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase()")
                    .localDirectory(new File(localDir))
                    .remoteFileSeparator("/"),
                    new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                            e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                                    .autoStartup(true)
                                    .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000)
                                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(1));
                        }
                    })
            //.channel(MessageChannels.queue("sftpInboundResultChannel"))
                    .channel(sftpInboundResultChannel())
            .get();
}
```

As suggested by Gary I am editing my post....

Hi Gary,
I am taking the reference from [Github dynamic FTP example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/ftp/DynamicFtpChannelResolver.java).

Through the ChannelResolver class I need to call my above DSL class. and set the dynamic value in context property without using XML.

In my ChannelResolver class I want some thing like this

```
StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("inbound.host", host);    //I am getting the value of 'host' from a DB table.
PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("sftpprop", props);
env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
context.setEnvironment(env); 

And my DSL class I need to use like this.
@Value("${inbound.host}")
private String host;

So in this way can I set dynamic value for String 'host' ?
```

I am editing my original post...........

```
In my Outbound dynamic resolver class I am doing like this


    StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
    Properties props = new Properties();        
    props.setProperty("outbound.host", host);
    props.setProperty("outbound.port", String.valueOf(port));
    props.setProperty("outbound.user", user);
    props.setProperty("outbound.password", password);
    props.setProperty("outbound.remote.directory", remoteDir);
    props.setProperty("outbound.local.directory", localDir);        

    PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("ftpprops", props);
    env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
    ctx.setEnvironment(env);


And this is my dsl class....

@Autowired
private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;

@Bean
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory(@Value("${outbound.host}") String host, @Value("${outbound.port}") int port,
        @Value("${outbound.user}") String user, @Value("${outbound.password}") String password
        ) {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setUser(user);
    factory.setPassword(password);      
    return factory;
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileInboundFlow(@Value("${outbound.local.directory}") String localDir)
{
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(localDir)),
                    new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {

                        @Override
                        public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                            e.autoStartup(true).poller(
                                    Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)
                                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(1));
                        }
                    })
                    .channel(sftpSendChannel())
                    .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundFlow(@Value("${outbound.remote.directory}") String remDir) {    
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(sftpSendChannel())
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)                       
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(remDir))
                    .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel sftpSendChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer1() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();      
}


And this the error log from console...
```

Aug 03, 2015 7:50:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sftpOutBoundDsl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory com.tcs.iux.ieg.sftp.dynamic.SftpOutBoundDsl.sftpSessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'outbound.host' in string value "${outbound.host}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory com.tcs.iux.ieg.sftp.dynamic.SftpOutBoundDsl.sftpSessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'outbound.host' in string value "${outbound.host}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'outbound.host' in string value "${outbound.host}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:743)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:466)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1088)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 24 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not supported.

We have an [open JIRA to add support for dynamic server selection](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3491) but it's unlikely to be done in time for the upcoming 4.2 release.

You could work around it by writing your own custom delegating session factory that uses some criteria (e.g. a `ThreadLocal`) to determine which delegate factory to use.

**EDIT:**

As with the XML, you need a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.

You should also use factory-method injection because the `@Configuration` class is created too early to have the `@Value` injected...

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory(
            @Value("${inbound.host}") String host, 
            @Value("${inbound.port}") int port) {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(host);
        sf.setPort(port);
        return sf;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

.

```
public class Testing {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(FooConfig.class);
        StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("inbound.host", "bar");
        props.setProperty("inbound.port", "23");
        PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("sftpprop", props);
        env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
        context.setEnvironment(env);
        context.refresh();
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory = context.getBean(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.class);
        assertEquals("bar", TestUtils.getPropertyValue(sessionFactory, "host"));
        context.close();
    }

}
```

By the way, [the delegating session factory will be in 4.2 after all](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1523).

**EDIT2**:

You can avoid the early instantiation of the config class and use global `@Value` injection, as long as you make the PSPC bean `static`...

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfig {

    @Value("${foo}")
    public String foo;

    @Bean
    public String earlyFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

    @Bean
    public String foo(@Value("${foo}") String foo) {
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

In this case, `earlyFoo` is populated as expected.

Comment: Hi Gary, How could I set dynamic property value for Sftp session using @Value annotation. Can I use like this ....StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("inbound.host", host);
PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("sftpprop", props);
env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
context.setEnvironment(env);            and my session variable I need to use like this .. @Value("${inbound.host}").

Comment: Really stuck at this point , could you please provide any pointer on this.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - it doesn't render well; edit your question instead.

Comment: Hi Gary, I have edited my question in the original post. So could you please provide any pointer on this.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks a ton, I am going to implement this in my project.

Comment: Hi Gary, For dynamic inbound flow it works fine but when I have done for this in out bound flow , exception comes like ....Could not resolve placeholder 'outbound.host' in string value "${outbound.host}"  .  So could you please provide any pointer on this.

Comment: Sounds like the properties are not being injected properly; turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework and watch the placeholders being resolved. If you still can't figure it out, post the exact code that fails.

Comment: HI Gary, I could not able to figure it out so I have posted my code in my original post. Could you please provide any pointer on this.

Comment: Nothing stands out to me. I suggest you compare the debug logs from the one that works to the one that doesn't and see if you can tell what's different. If you still can't figure it out, post the logs someplace (e.g. github gist or pastebin). You should also consider using factory method injection for the session factory instead of autowiring it into the configuration bean.

Comment: Hi Gary, The same code is working fine in debug mode but when I am trying to run it directly it halts due to exceptions.

Comment: There must be something different between the environments; I can't help you with that; you'll need to figure it out, sorry. If you can reproduce with a small test case, post it somewhere like GitHub and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Gary, I found the prblem. In debug mode when I am putting any file in the local folder then the polling is working fine and file is getting copied to the remote folder but 
in run mode  I am not able to do that , then the program halts. When I have paused the thread for some time by Thread.sleep() after refreshing the context and put some file in the local directory in that 
mean time, then the polling is working fine. I think AbstractPollingEndpoint is not working properly ,So not able to fix the issue. Could you please provide any pointer on this.

Comment: You must be shutting down the JVM prematurely. `AbstractPollingEndpoint is not working properly` - I seriously doubt that. As I said in my last comment, you need to provide a test case that reproduces the issue; otherwise I can't help you.